# How can we change the semantic to LTR of a tableview cell when the whole screen is set as RTL?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arabic

The screen is in the Arabic language and it's semantic is set right to left. The whole screen consists of a table view with customs cells. I need to change the semantics of one of the cells in the table view to left to right. The cell has two text fields side by side

I have tried                                 `cell.countryCodeField.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight`
which is not working

[my custom cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cj5x.png)

```
class EditmobileNumberCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mobileNumberField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var countryCodeField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var hintLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mobileNoPlaceHolder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var backView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
            countryCodeField.addRightImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icMobileDropdown"), contMode: .bottom)

        mobileNumberField.textAlignment = .left
        countryCodeField.textAlignment = .left
        hintLabel.textAlignment = .left
        mobileNoPlaceHolder.textAlignment = .left
        mobileNumberField.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        countryCodeField.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        hintLabel.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        mobileNoPlaceHolder.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just take view in cell and all controllers place in side the view and make view semanticContentAttribute to forceLeftToRight

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a view inside the cell and add all the controllers inside it and then use view semanticContentAttribute to forceLeftToRight, in the above case write inside awakeFromNib() -

`backView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight`

This worked for me

Answer (score 4):

You need to change `semanticContentAttribute` for the tableView, changing the cell `semanticContentAttribute` won't do any change.

```
tableView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

That should get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Try `cell.contentView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight`

Answer (score -1):

Just uncheck your 'Respect language direction' from your leading/trailing constraints in storyboard. then your semantic thing will work for that specific cell:

[image]